# How can we make a generic UI in phonegap for all platforms?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I have been working on a cross platform project. I am a beginner to Phonegap. The problem is that I have to re-skinned a cross platform application. I re-skinned the whole application using inline css. Now When I run the application on different devices the UI of application displays differently for each device. How can I convert it into a generic UI?

Comment: How can be this possible? If you have one CSS, the styles will be the same in all the platforms

Comment: actually another developer had developed the whole application using dev-express. The other developer worked on the same project and re-skinned the whole project using inline. Now the project is running fine on iphone5. But when we test it on other devices it has some padding and margin issues. Now we want to overcome those issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this framework?](https://app-framework-software.intel.com/)

It mimics the natural UI depending on what phone you are using.

Comment: actually another developer had developed the whole application using dev-express. The other developer worked on the same project and re-skinned the whole project using inline. Now the project is running fine on iphone5. But when we test it on other devices it has some padding and margin issues. Now we want to overcome those issues.

Comment: You could use Cordova's platform specific overrides to address this, see the "Using merges to Customize Each Platform" section at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/cli/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phonegap then go for Angular JS for Universal or Generic UI.

ReasonS for angular JS are:

- It's MVC architecture.
- Mainly It adjusts it's UI based upon mobile screen, so no worry about different screen sizes.
- two way data binding.
- will not change UI device to device.

You can overcome almost all your UI generic issues by using AngularJS.

This [link](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-phonegap) may help you.